# Session in AJAX calls

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, fancybox

I have a problem with my site.

See that pages:

- /index.php                   <- session_start()
- /includes/functions.php
- /modules/feedback.php        <- read some $_SESSION
- /gui/savefeedback.php    <- read some $_SESSION
- /ajaxGateway.php

In index.php there is a link. When I press that link, a fancybox2 popup appears. I pass that url to fancybox (/gui/savefeedback.php?somestuff=blablabla)

In that box I have a form with textarea and a submit button. I use the $_SESSION variable to configure some GUI element. In that page, I use jQuery with an AJAX call like /ajaxGateway?action=feedback

AjaxGateway simple parse the command and include /feedback.php?vote=1&comment=aaaaaaaaa

Problem!! In /modules/feedback.php I cannot read $_SESSION variable.

Why?

Comment: You need to do a `session_start()` for each request.

Comment: OptimusCrime, no, you should not call session_start in include():d files. Just call it once for each request.

Answer (score 3):

You need `session_start();` at that page(/modules/feedback.php).

Comment: I've already session_start() in index.php because i use the link like index.php?page=XXX. Infact if I use session_start() in /modules/feedback.php I receive the error "Session already started"...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using cookies, then each AJAX request handles cookies in exactly the same way as if you had browsed to the URLs manually...

[See here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1995-AJAX-Requests-Get-And-Set-Cookies-Like-Any-Other-HTTP-Request.htm) for more information

To confirm everything is working, what happens if you browse manually to those URLs? are you `session_start()`'ing on every page?

Comment: I dont know why, but when I go manually in that URL I have a weird stuff. E.G. in saveFeedback.php I must change include_once('../../modules/feedback.php'); to include_once('modules/feedback.php'); otherwise I got some include errors..

Comment: If it doesn't work in your browser, it's not going to work via AJAX - All AJAX is doing is browsing to the page and giving the response to your JavaScript code instead of rendering it... You need to make the pages work properly before calling them with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Start every page with `if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();`  If you just do `session_start();` it might throw an error if your session is already started on another page.